# Yii2 how can an model attribute is modified after load method? (like the afterFind method)

Tags: yii2

I have an attribute of the model which should be modified after it's loaded from the database.

I could extend the afterFind method, which could the convert the varchar value to a php array. So it works find.

But when the model is loaded I have no idea how to convert that varchar to the php array.

I have tried with rules but does not works:

```
[['languages'], 'each', 'rule' => ['string']],
```

or this one

```
[['languages'], 'safe'],
```

So this one works afterFind:

```
public function afterFind()
{
    $this->languages = $this->convertToPHPArray($this->languages);
    parent::afterFind();
}
```

By the way I have tried to extend the **init** or the **__constructor** method with this conversation, but no success, after **load** method the languages attribute is still a string instead of a php array.

Comment: why there isn't an `afterLoad` event [yii2/issues/4615](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4615), reading the whole thread may give some idea

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, I think that you could use a property in the model:

```
public class Model {

      public function getLanguagesArray()
     {
             return $this->convertToPHPArray($this->languages);

     }

}
```

Then, use it:

```
$arr = $model->languagesArray;
```